# SQLite Trigger for composite primary key with autoincrement value

Tags: sqlite, composite-primary-key, composite-key, database-trigger

I am developing an application with AspNetCore and Entity Framework Core which supports two DB providers, SqlServer and Sqlite. I defined the following Code First classes

```
public class Document {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentSection {
    public Guid DocumentId { get; set; }
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
}
```

When simply declaring `SectionId` as autoincremented, this works fine for SqlServer but Sqlite doesn't support this.

The optimal end result I'd like to have is (let `DocumentId` be an `int` for simplicity)

```
PK

(1)   Document XYZ
(2)   Document foo

(1,1) Header Section (Doc 1)
(1,2) Main Body      (Doc 1)
(2,1) Header         (Doc 2)
(2,2) Body           (Doc 2)
(2,3) Footer         (Doc 2)
```

Just setting part of the composite key as autoincremented works with SqlServer, SQLite doesn't support this out of the box, though. This is actually OK since I'm not expecting to come anywhere close to `int.MAX`. So the "suboptimal" solution working on SqlServer generates the following:

```
(1,1)
(1,2)
(2,3)
(2,4)
(2,5)
```

This can be solved with a trigger but my SQL skills are close to non-existent. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SectionTrigger
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON DocumentSection
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO DocumentSection (DocumentId, SectionId, otherValue)
    VALUES (
      NEW.DocumentId,
      (SELECT max(SectionId) + 1 FROM DocumentSection WHERE DocumentId = NEW.DocumentId),
      NEW.otherValue);
END;
```

results to

```
cannot create INSTEAD OF trigger on table: ContractSection: CREATE TRIGGER SectionTrigger
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON ContractSection
BEGIN
```

I had a look at the [Create Trigger Documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) but could't figure it out. I guess I could live with the "suboptimal" solution for SqlServer (and Sqlite too) since adding triggers requires to edit EF Core migration code manually which I'd like to prevent of course.

**edit**: an AFTER trigger would be fine, too of course.

Comment: INSTEAD OF triggers require a view. Why not an AFTER trigger?

Comment: Yikes, now that you mention it, I think I've even read somewhere on SO that this only works on views. Of course an AFTER trigger is fine, too. How would an AFTER trigger work in this case? Since the autoincrement value is part of the PK, in case I insert multiple rows would this trigger get triggered for each row one after another to prevent inserting multiple rows with the same PK? Any considerations I need to make regarding performance?

Comment: What happens when you try it?